# Re-using React Components

Tags: reactjs

I've been doing React lessons, but one thing I don't ever see done is reusing components. For example, if I had a button, and wanted to produce a div every time that button was clicked. How would I do it using a React component that's sole purpose is rendering a single div, And that button uses that one component to add additional divs to the page every time it's clicked?

Comment: am I right in assuming the button is a react component?

Comment: first of all, are you asking the general question of how react reuses components? or the specific question, how to make a button render a new div on click?

Comment: I'm not asking in general how they work. I get that you can make a component, and then you can render it to the DOM. I'm wondering how you can reuse a component and make a _new_ instance of it. Like say I'm making a scoring web app and want to add new players. I want to use the same structured div, but I want it to add a new player every time the add player is clicked.

Would the best way to do this be having the player div map an array of players every time the add player is clicked, and then have the button just add information to an object array?

Comment: that player would be some kind of dataset that is in some state that then gets mapped through a render function (pretty much like in my example where the divs contain a text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean, something like this?

The `CustomButton` stateless component (presentational) just receives props and can be disabled, text can be changed and a callback can be defined. It doesn't have any own state and can be reused throughout your app where you might need a button.

The `ButtonSampleApp` is a container component that uses the presentional component and supplies it with a callback, and then handles that callback. To add a div in it's rendering. The `ButtonSampleApp` uses component state to achieve this

```js
const CustomButton = ({ text, callback, isEnabled }) => {
  return <button onClick={() => callback()} disabled={!isEnabled} type="button">{ text }</button>;
};

class ButtonSampleApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      divs: []
    };
  }
  onButtonClicked() {
    const { divs } = this.state;
    this.setState( { divs: [...divs, { text: divs.length }] });
  }
  render() {
    const { max } = this.props;
    const { divs } = this.state;
    return (<div>
      <h1>Click on button to add a max of { max } divs</h1>
      <div>
      { divs && divs.map( ({text}) => <div key={text}>{ text }</div> ) }
      </div>
      <CustomButton isEnabled={!divs || divs.length < max}  text="Add button" callback={() => this.onButtonClicked()} />
    </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <ButtonSampleApp max={10} />, document.querySelector('#container') );
```

```html
<script id="react" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.js"></script>
<script id="react-dom" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```